# C# - Use runtime-defined type as parameter in generic method

Tags: c#, reflection, types

This is what i'm trying to do:

```
PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = GetProperties(typeofEntity);
Type t = propertyInfos[0].GetType();
IList<t.GetType()> magicalList;
```

Let us say that t happens to be of type Int32, i then want the list to be

```
IList<Int32>
```

This doesn't work, as it's just the same as doing

```
IList<Type>
```

I don't want to write a dozen casts to manually find the Type.

Any Ideas?
Thanks

EDIT---------------

I'm doing this because i wanto to pass an object no an NHibernate query, and automatically create the criterias corresponding to the values of the object's properties.

Ex:

```
Person{
public string Name
public Phone Phone 
}

Phone{
public int Number
}
```

I want to be able to create a person with a phone, and pass it in an nhibernate query, using DetachedFor<>. I then want to automatically create criterias for the properties of 'complex' properties of Person, such as Phone.Number.

Comment: Can you add some more code to describe why you're doing this? Might be a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
var genericType = typeof (List<>).MakeGenericType(t.GetType());
var magicalList = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can only use generics with a known type at compile-time.
In your code, the expression `magicalList[0]` would have no compile-time type.

You can either use a non-generic `IList` or do everything with reflection.

Answer (score 1):

There is the method System.Type.MakeGenericType wich help to create generic type passing the arguments. In your case you have the main type :

```
var oGenericType = typeof (IList<>);
var oSpecificType = oGenericType.MakeGenericType(typeof(int));
```